# How can I automatically identify the type of free term in an equation and shift it?

Tags: expression-manipulation, algebraic-manipulation

How can I automatically identify the type of term in an equation and shift it to the left of the equal sign in this equation? The quadratic terms containing `x` and `y` should remain on the left side of the equation. How to automatically identify terms `(a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2` that do not contain `x` and `y` in the equation and move them to the right side of the equation?

```
y^2 - (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == 0
```

The equation obtained according to the above rules is:

```
y^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2
```

I tried to write it myself (code below), but is there a better way?

```
ClearAll["`*"]

eq = y^2 - (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == 0

pl = Apply[Subtract, eq]
term = First@CoefficientList[pl, y][[1]]
SubtractSides[eq, term]

(* y^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 *)
```

Comment: Did you try `CoefficientList`? This gives you desired terms (free of X and Y) as coefficients of the zero power of X and Y.

Comment: ```ClearAll["`*"]
eq = y^2 - (a^2 \[Lambda]^2)/(-1 + \[Lambda]^2)^2 + (x - (a \
\[Lambda]^2)/(-1 + \[Lambda]^2))^2 == 0
Apply[Subtract, eq]
First@Flatten@CoefficientList[%, {x, y}]```how to do it?

Comment: @Rom38 The structure of the equation cannot be destroyed, which means that the complete square term cannot be reopened when extracting coefficients

Comment: ```ClearAll["`*"]
eq = y^2 - (a^2 \[Lambda]^2)/(-1 + \[Lambda]^2)^2 + (x - (a \
\[Lambda]^2)/(-1 + \[Lambda]^2))^2 == 0
pl = Apply[Subtract, eq]
List @@ pl

Coefficient[List @@ pl, x, 0]
Coefficient[List @@ pl, y, 0]
SubtractSides[eq, term]```

Comment: Replace[eq, 
 x1___ + x2_ + x3___ == 0 /; FreeQ[x2, x | y] :> Plus[x1, x3] == -x2]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`FreeQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) to identify terms without `x` or `y`.

```
Fold[SubtractSides, eq, Select[List @@ First@eq, FreeQ[x | y]]]

(* y^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 *)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
eq = y^2 - (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == 0;
terms = Cases[eq, a_?(FreeQ[x | y]), {2}]
(* {-((a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2)} *)
SubtractSides[eq, Total@terms]
(* y^2 + (x - (a λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2))^2 == (a^2 λ^2)/(-1 + λ^2)^2 *)
```

Alternatively, for the last step:

```
Thread[eq - Total[terms], Equal]
```